# Explicação de um array php e como aceder à posição x do array PHP

Tags: php

Preciso de uma breve explicação sobre arrays em php já fui pesquisar e sem sucesso.

Por exemplo se tentar algo do género onde estou a buscar os horarios as basededados o echo não funciona estou tambem a trabalhar com ajax

```
<?php
    $count=0;
    while ($dados = mysql_fetch_array($result){
        $count=$count+1;
         $hora= $dados['horarioHora'];

        }
    }echo $hora[$count];
?>
```

Comment: Não deu pra entender o que o echo deveria retornar?

Comment: A ultima hora que esta na base de dados já editei o meu código espero que agora seja mais facil

Answer (score 1, accepted):

bom ali no caso você tem uma variável hora e não um array.

para ser array deveria ter feito

```
<?php
    $count=0;
    while ($arrayDisp = mysql_fetch_array($result){
        $count=$count+1;
        $hora[] = $arrayDisp['horarioHora'];

    }
    echo $hora[$count -1];
?>
```

Você também estava jogando o result do seu select para um array e lendo outra coisa.
Dessa forma ai vai pegar a ultima posição do array agora se é a hora mais recente depende da sua consulta mais especificamente do order by.
Não testei, mas acho que isso deve resolver, espero ter ajudado.

Comment: Funcionou era esse  o problema os []